# How to link Azure Bot with SharePoint?

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, bots, azure-qna-maker

I'm working on a bot service where we need to place the Bot in SharePoint Site. I have created a QnA Bot in Azure with sample KB and is working fine. Now i need the integration, can someone put some light on how I can achieve this ? Any links or documentation or tips will be helpful.

Comment: You can use - i Frame link from channels -> Get bot embed codes to embed bot on SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to embed chatbot on SharePoint using iFrame. We can get the embed code by navigating to

1. Bot channel registration in Azure.
2. Channels
3. Choose the channel you
   need embed code for. (In my case I chose webchat)

You can will get code like below

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/MyBotChannelReg?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'></iframe>
```

4. Copy any of the secret-key from above boxes and place the code in embed web part in SharePoint online.

you can adjust width and height of the chat box by adding width and height with iFrame code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the below component and deployed as webpart component in SharePoint app catalog.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-bot-framework

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great sample for your reference:

[integrate azure chat bot with sharepoint](https://www.anupams.net/integrate-azure-chat-bot-sharepoint/)